# Flutter shows Device list,but does not run

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio-3.0

As you can see that there are two devices being shown in the IDEA. But when I run it. It displays the below error that  "Unable to locate a development device; please run 'flutter doctor' for information about installing additional components."
[image]

Also here is the Response of the Flutter doctor. There is a very strange behavior, when I run flutter doctor, It shows me 2 devices connected when actually are, but when I run the same command again it shows me no devices connected. Basically it shows me these responses in alternate manner. Here is the screenshot for the same.
[image]

Here is one more strange behavior of Flutter. Screenshot for the same provided here below
[image]
Is it not stable with Ubuntu or something?
Any help is welcome.

Comment: Both are real devices?

Comment: One is Emulator, the other one is real device.

Comment: I have a same issue. Did you solved this?

Comment: No I have not been able to solve it yet. Still looking for solution

Comment: I am having the same issue on Ubuntu.

Comment: This may solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51267109/flutter-emulator-launched-but-not-detected-by-android-studio/53557131#53557131

Answer (score 2):

I got the same *"Unable to locate a development device; please run 'flutter doctor' for information about installing additional components."* error in Android Studio 3.1.4.

It turned out that I had an old version of **adb** dated from 2014(!) inside **/usr/bin/** and a new version in **~/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/** (your path may vary).

As root I made:

- `cd /usr/bin`
- `mv adb adb_old`
- `ln -s ~/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb adb` (look out for **your** correct path!)

That solved it for me.

HTH, regards.

edit:
My problem originated from a really old misconfiguration. If your ANDROID_HOME and/or(?) ANDROID_SDK env-variables are pointing to the correct paths, it should be ok. - For my case I just issued a `which adb` and then headed directly to my solution steps. Resumee: the path and version of **adb** do matter!

Answer (score 0):

You try to connect only to one device and run `flutter run` in terminal.

Comment: It still throws the issues and in very strange Manner. Adding a screenshot for the same.

Comment: Please check the screenshot I added in my question

Comment: On Mi-A1 devices. Are you sure opened developer options -> USB debugging?

Answer (score 0):

Try a few things

- Make sure that developer mode is activated on your device (including usb debugging).
- Suitable driver is installed on the system for the device.
- Use the latest version of SDK.
- Run `flutter clean` before installation.
- Use this command in case of multiple devices connected `flutter run -d Mi A1`
- You can also check that cable is properly connected and supports data transfer

If issue still persist then report an issue on github.

Hope it helps..!

Comment: The issue still persists. I guess I will have to report it on github.